# How can I change this DB2 SQL query to a Right Join at the point indicated..?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm working on a vintage AS/400 DB2 system with v6r1m0. I working on a query that began in Access 2007, but then moved to DBeaver v5.1.5.201808130751. For those not familiar, this is an SQL client similar to SQL Explorer and SQL Squirrel.

I've created the SQL shown below, which seems to work well. Two of the sub-selects were too slow as client-side queries in Access, so I created them as server-side views, which worked better but still had room for improvement. Then I converted & merged everything into a single DB2 server-side query in DBeaver, and now it's lightning fast.

However, there's a point in the SQL where I think I need a `Right Join`, since I need to see rows with no match in the left table (which is actually a subquery). If I do this in Access, I get error 3258...

> "The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous
>   outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a
>   separate query that performs the first join and then include that
>   query in your SQL statement."

...and if I do it in DBeaver, it works as if nothing changed, like it's still an `Inner Join`. There are no error messages, and the same number of records is returned, although I know for certain there should be exactly 23 more.

I understand from the Access error that I need to create a subquery for the part with the `Right Join`, but the complexity of the query is such that I'm not sure how to do it.

How can I create the subquery as instructed by the Access error..??

The SQL is below. The point needing the `Right Join` has a comment, about 10 lines from the end of the query. I need to see all records from `BEERXT`, with any matching records from the subquery `RATES`. My expectation is that fields from `RATES` with no match would return as null.

Note: This database is an ancient order & inventory system with a variety of data stored in un-normalized & pivoted format. The `Union` subqueries are used to un-pivot such tables.

```
SELECT 

LOADS.EMPID                 AS EMPID, 
LOADS.LDROLE                AS EMPROLE,
EMPLS.LHNAME                AS EMPNAME, 
DAILY.DAIDAT                AS INVDATE, 
DAILY.DAINV#                AS INVNUM, 
DAILY.DADAY#                AS INVDY, 
DAILY.DALOAD                AS LOAD, 
DAILY.DALIN#                AS INVLN, 
DAILY.DAITEM                AS ITEM, 
DAILY.DAUM                  AS UOM, 
DAILY.DAPCLS                AS CLASS, 
BEER.BXADDS                 AS BXDESC, 
BEER.BXDESC                 AS BXPKG, 
BEER.BXCCAT                 AS BXCAT, 
RATES.TYPECD                AS LDTYPE, 
RATES.RATECD                AS CMRCD, 
RATES.CMDESC                AS CMRDSC, 
RATES.CMRATE                AS CMRATE,
DAILY.DAQTY                 AS QTY, 
DAILY.DAQTY*RATES.CMRATE    AS SUBTOT

FROM VIPDTAB.LDHDR AS EMPLS 
    INNER JOIN (--THE FOLLOWING SUBSELECT IS TO UNPIVOT LDHIST
    (         SELECT LIYMD AS LDDATE, LILOAD AS LDNUM, LITRCK AS LDTRCK, 1 AS LDROLE, LIDRIV AS EMPID, COALESCE(LIRAT1,'0') AS BRATE, COALESCE(LICRT1,'0') AS CRATE FROM VIPDTAB.LDHIST WHERE CAST(LIDRIV AS INTEGER)>0 
        UNION SELECT LIYMD AS LDDATE, LILOAD AS LDNUM, LITRCK AS LDTRCK, 2 AS LDROLE, LIDRIV AS EMPID, COALESCE(LIRAT2,'0') AS BRATE, COALESCE(LICRT2,'0') AS CRATE FROM VIPDTAB.LDHIST WHERE CAST(LIHLP1 AS INTEGER)>0 
        UNION SELECT LIYMD AS LDDATE, LILOAD AS LDNUM, LITRCK AS LDTRCK, 3 AS LDROLE, LIDRIV AS EMPID, COALESCE(LIRAT3,'0') AS BRATE, COALESCE(LICRT3,'0') AS CRATE FROM VIPDTAB.LDHIST WHERE CAST(LIHLP2 AS INTEGER)>0
    ) AS LOADS
        INNER JOIN (--THE FOLLOWING SUBSELECT IS TO UNPIVOT LDHRAT
            (         SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 0 AS UNCODE,        0 AS LOWLIM,      0 AS UPRLIM,      0 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT 
                UNION SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 1 AS UNCODE,        1 AS LOWLIM, LRQTY1 AS UPRLIM, LRRAT1 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT
                UNION SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 2 AS UNCODE, LRQTY1+1 AS LOWLIM, LRQTY2 AS UPRLIM, LRRAT2 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT
                UNION SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 3 AS UNCODE, LRQTY2+1 AS LOWLIM, LRQTY3 AS UPRLIM, LRRAT3 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT
                UNION SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 4 AS UNCODE, LRQTY3+1 AS LOWLIM, LRQTY4 AS UPRLIM, LRRAT4 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT
                UNION SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 5 AS UNCODE, LRQTY4+1 AS LOWLIM, LRQTY5 AS UPRLIM, LRRAT5 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT
                UNION SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 6 AS UNCODE, LRQTY5+1 AS LOWLIM, LRQTY6 AS UPRLIM, LRRAT6 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT
                UNION SELECT LRCATG AS CATG, LRLDTY AS TYPECD, LRCRAT AS RATECD, 7 AS UNCODE, LRQTY6+1 AS LOWLIM, LRQTY7 AS UPRLIM, LRRAT7 AS CMRATE, LRCOLH AS CMDESC FROM VIPDTAB.LDHRAT
            ) AS RATES  
            INNER JOIN (VIPDTAB.BEERXT AS BEER --THIS NEEDS TO BE A RIGHT JOIN (I THINK?)
                INNER JOIN VIPDTAB.DAILYT AS DAILY 
                ON BEER.BXITEM = DAILY.DAITEM 
            ) ON RATES.CATG = BEER.BXCCAT
        ) ON (LOADS.LDDATE = DAILY.DAIDAT) AND (LOADS.LDNUM = DAILY.DALOAD) AND (LOADS.CRATE = RATES.RATECD)
    ) ON EMPLS.LHDRIV = LOADS.EMPID

WHERE DAILY.DAIDAT=20180716 AND LOADS.EMPID=36137 AND (DAILY.DAQTY BETWEEN LOWLIM AND UPRLIM)

ORDER BY LOADS.EMPID, DAILY.DAIDAT, DAILY.DAINV#, DAILY.DALIN#, BEER.BXCCAT, RATES.TYPECD, RATES.RATECD;
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start!

Comment: I would be happy to, if not for the fact that there are five tables in the query, and two of them are over 100 columns wide.

Comment: So simplify the problem. Did you check the link?

Comment: Yes. I've been working on this query for days, trying different approaches. What you see in my post is the result of condensing chunks of SQL from a variety of different queries. But the crisscrossing nature of the joins seems to make what I need impossible. I would not have asked for help here if I had not performed all due diligence to attempt a solution on my own.

Comment: ....Despite the existence of `RIGHT JOIN`, I've always found it easier/clearer to _start_ with a table I know will "always" have rows, then `LEFT JOIN` to rows that may not exist.  So make `BEERXT` the main/`FROM` table, then `LEFT JOIN` to `RATES`, etc.  Also, some notes: If all you're doing is `INNER JOIN`ing tables, you shouldn't need to nest the join; just leave it at the same level.  And put as many conditions as possible into the `ON` statement ; reserve `WHERE` from the table referenced in `FROM` (and some special cases which aren't relevant in the AS/400 DB2)

Comment: There's still quite a bit you could do to simplify this problem to track down your issue. The first thing would be to dump the results of each of the "Union" queries to their own temporary tables for testing purposes.  That would remove a lot of the clutter that isn't relevant to the problem. When I did so, it is apparent that there is a circular dependency between the BEER, DAILY, and RATES tables. This is quite likely to be the cause of your ambiguity error when you perform a right join

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Wow, I didn't know the joins could be un-nested. For anything more than two tables, I've always started with Microsoft Access and edited the SQL from there. But I see now the first table added is the deepest-nested. So I spent a day un-nesting everything, and wow what a difference..! This single tip is a godsend..! I discovered with `JOIN` and `ON()` on the same line, I can just swap the lines around to troubleshoot issues with `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`. With Access everything was upside down..! Now the most important table is at the top. So much easier, lol.

Comment: @Player1st, yes I vaguely recognized the circularity of the joins, but I wasn't sure if it was a problem, nor what to do if it was. The tip from @Clockwork-Muse to un-nest the joins was the key to much easier troubleshooting. I rebuilt everything from the top down, and found I can simply put the `LEFT JOIN` last and it worked. I also experimented with moving the `BETWEEN` from the `WHERE` to the appropriate `ON` and was quite surprised to find that it worked and solved the issue of missing rows with nulls in the "right" table. You can't compare a null value. Duh. lol

Comment: ...The order of lines shouldn't matter; SQL works based on "set" math, looking for _all_ rows that meet certain criteria, which is going to include joins.  This also means SQL is also a (mostly) declarative language - you generally don't control the actual execution, instead there's an optimizer which controls which tables/rows/columns are visited first (and also means short-circuit logic doesn't work)

Comment: Side note: (personal style preference) Please forget `BETWEEN` exists, and instead always explicitly input your ranges: For anything that is **NOT** an integer, the inclusive upper bound (on positive values) is going to cause what amount to off-by-one/'fencepost' errors.  Instead, you should always be using an exclusive upper-bound with any positive values, `<`, to avoid this.

Comment: Ahhh, you mean `x >= y AND x < z`..? Ok I see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error. I have a strong background in electronics and digital audio (I was a broadcast radio technician) and in the world of analog-to-digital conversion, it's called "dithering". Anywho, thanks for the tip; I'll remember it and apply as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat complex query because you have a lot of nested joins. I can't really give you a real answer without sample data, and the desired output, but I can potentially assist your troubleshooting. This is what I see in the joins (including the desired right outer join):

First join is to be executed is an inner join between BEER and DAILY on BEER.BXITEM = DAILY.DAITEM. This will filter out any BEER records that are not in the DAILY table.

Second join: The results of this first join are then to be joined to RATES using a RIGHT OUTER JOIN on RATES.CATG = BEER.BXCCAT. Remaining BEER records that do not have a match in RATES will still be there, but the resultset will have nulls for the RATES fields.

Third join: The results of the second join are then joined to LOADS using an INNER JOIN on (LOADS.LDDATE = DAILY.DAIDAT) AND (LOADS.LDNUM = DAILY.DALOAD) AND (LOADS.CRATE = RATES.RATECD). That last term will filter out any RATES records that have a null in RATECD. If you want to include the rows from the result set with missing RATES values, this will need to be a RIGHT OUTER JOIN as well, but it will now also include any rows that have a RATECD in RATES, but no matching CRATE in LOADS, or failed on either of the other join criteria.

Fourth join: The results of this join is finally joined to EMPLS using an INNER JOIN on EMPLS.LHDRIV = LOADS.EMPID. Once again this will filter out any rows in the resultset where LOADS.EMPID is null, which would be any row that is missing the RATES record (given that you converted the third join to a RIGHT OUTER JOIN). Once again you would need another RIGHT OUTER JOIN to get those records, but once again, you could also pick up additional records that you don't want.

My best suggestion given that you don't want to provide sample data and output, is to start with the innermost join, and work you way out with appropriate join types and WHERE clauses until you get what you want.